# On group that has no non-abelian subgroup of order 6

Tags: group-theory

Do there exits a group $G$ such that $G$ has not a non-abelian subgroup of order 6, but $Inn(G)$ is isomorphic to a non abelian group of order 6?

Thank you

We know that $\dfrac{G}{Z(G)}\cong Inn(G)$. also $S_{3}$ is only non abelian group of order 6. Also if $Z(G)$ is odd, then there is not this group. therefore i think the center $G$ to be even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a group $G=\langle x,y \mid x^3=y^4=1, y^{-1}xy=x^{-1} \rangle$ of order $12$ with $|Z(G)|=2$ and $G/Z(G)$ nonabelian of order $6$, and $G$ has no subgroup that is nonabelian of order $6$.